# How to display certain fields in a dbGrid where the parent table's ID matches with the child table's ID

Tags: database, delphi-2010

so i am creating trying to display all Game names on a certain platform based on the users choice from a combobox. eg if the user selects playstation all the playstaion games must be displayed and so.
Interface design
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgV8j.png)
db design parent table
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfBx1.png)
child table
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkEiZ.png)

I tried using filter but it only displays the first field. i want to display all playstation games
code i used
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0KcT.png)
output i got
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz9PD.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please try to avoid posting data or code as images - it breaks screen readers and can't be copy-pasted which makes it much harder for people to reproduce your issue and try to help you.  If you can include your progress so far as a more usable format you are likely to receive better help.